# I cannot import summer notes in django

Tags: python, django, import, summernote

when i try to import summernoteModelAdmin in admin using `from djangosummernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin` it shows error  `Import "djangosummernote.admin" could not be resolved`

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from djangosummernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

from .models import BlogPost

class BlogPostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('content')

admin.site.register(BlogPost, BlogPostAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a typo in the import of the module.

It is:

`from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin`

not

`from djangosummernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin`